Why does using a mutable default argument in a Python function cause unexpected behavior?
I'm learning Python and came across an issue with default arguments in functions. Here's an example of my code:
def add_to_list(value, my_list=[]):
    my_list.append(value)
    return my_list

print(add_to_list(1))  
print(add_to_list(2))  

I expected the second call to return [2], but it returned [1, 2].
Why is this happening?
How can I modify the function so that the default argument doesn’t retain values from previous calls?

https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Why always close new contributor questions? What kind of welcome is this? lol

You should write like this: add_to_list(value, my_list=None) and then in the function you should add a check: if my_list is None: my_list = [].
I'm sorry I cannot answer properly 'cause some incompetent closed your question.
